# Can we get response in DRL file from a called method?

Tags: drools, optaplanner

I have a scenario where I need to call a static method in DRL file.
example :

```
//2
rule "availableTentativeDateIfUsersAvailableGT1"
    salience 2
when
    event  : Event(eventName == "Event1")
then
    getDates(event.parameterization.usersAvailability);
end
```

Now i need to get the response from the method in DRL. Is it possible?

Comment: You can call static methods with no trouble.

Comment: but how can i get an object in return and how can i access it in DRL?

Comment: For more constructive answers, add the Java code of that static method. BTW, the consequence code (between "then" and "end") is plain old Java, with extensions (insert, delete, modify).

Comment: public static void getDates(def usersAvailability){
  TentativeDate tentativeDate = new TentativeDate();
  List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();
  println "usersAvailability : " +usersAvailability 
  for(Date date : dateWithAvailableUserCount.keySet()){
   Integer noOfUsers =  dateWithAvailableUserCount.get(date)   
   if(noOfUsers>=usersAvailability){
    dates.add(date);
    println "Tentative Date  is : " + date + " and number of available users : " + noOfUsers;
   }
  }
  tentativeDate.setTentativeDates(dates); 
 }  This is a piece of code of my static method

Comment: I have used insert(getDates(event.parameterization.usersAvailability)) in drl file.
Now how can i access TentativeDate(which is return type of method) in java file?

Comment: anyone please suggest some solution how can i access the objects from working memory using optaplanner?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you wish to accomplish. If you want to explain to the user why a certain solution has a certain score (so which entities trigger which score constraints), [get the ConstraintMatches](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#reusingTheScoreCalculationOutsideTheSolver).

Comment: Actually i have put an object in working memory using insert in DRL file now i need to get that object in JAVA file.
Is it clear now?

Comment: any update on this question?

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet : Can you update about this question as not able to get the solution of this.